# Force Include of an entity in the context while still lazy loading the rest in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a way to have lazy loading enabled, but still force the inclusion of certain properties **in the context**?

For example, I have a `Car` object that always has a `Vehicle` object. The `Car` might also have a `Body` object associated with it. When I fetch a `Car` object, I *always* want the `Vehicle` to come with the car (without having to write `.Include("Vehicle")` everywhere), but then do lazy loading when I try access `.Body`.

I have tried removing the `virtual` from the `Car`'s `Vehicle` property, but now it just returns `null`. How do I force the `Vehicle` to always be populated when I fetch a `Car`? Can I do something in `OnModelCreating()`?

Thanks!

Comment: why not use a help function, like public IQueryable<Car> GetCars(Expression<Func<Car,bool>> pred=null){return pred==null? this.Car.Include("Vehicle"): this.Car.Where(pred).Include("Vehicle");} ? EDIT: made code more practicable.

Comment: There's no way to configure it on the context level. Go with @DevilSuichiro suggestion. Also, you have to remember that the `virtual` keyword only *allows* Lazy-Loading, no navigation property will be eager loaded without explicitly asking to.

Comment: Is there any way I can create a custom DbSet that would allow me to specify that somewhere? I am trying to keep it very generic so that outside of the context no one knows it is happening. I also want to apply the same thing to a couple of entities, without having to write a help function for each of them if possible.

Comment: actually, I don't think it works on DbSet level. I can't really try it out right now, but you could try putting it in the getter of the entry? or just hide the context behind an interface and implement the functionality there.

Comment: Just tried in the getter but `.Include` returns an `IQueryable` and can't get back to a DbSet from there (at least I don't think so). I will see if I can mask it behind an interface, but it would be great if I could do it somewhere generically like in the OnModelCreating() or with a custom DbSet.